# Swapping the first and the last letter of a string in Java?

Tags: java, string, char

```
int length = s.length();

if (length <= 1){
    return s;
}

else {

    return s.charAt(length) + s.substring(1, length-1) + s.charAt(0);

}
```

I'm just trying to swap the first letter and the last letter of a string.

eg. apple -> eppla

It compiled fine and works fine with an empty string or a string with one character only. 
But  with strings with several characters, it says:

```
StringIndexOutOfBoundsException occured - see console for stack trace
```

Does tht mean there's something wrong with my code???

Comment: Remember that length is one greater than the final element in the string. For example the String `word` is length 4 but charAt(3) is d

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
int length = s.length();

if (length <= 1) {
    return s;
} else {
    return s.charAt(length - 1) + s.substring(1, length - 1) + s.charAt(0);
}
```

The difference is `s.charAt(length - 1)`. Remember, the string is zero-indexed, so the last character is `s.charAt(length - 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

you want s.charAt(length - 1) to start off

Answer (score 0):

```
if(str.length()<=1){return str;}

String middle=str.substring(1,str.length()-1);

return str.charAt(str.length()-1)+middle+str.charAt(0);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String str;
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the String");
str=sc.nextLine();
String word[]=str.split(" ");
int len=word.length;
String temp=word[0];
word[0]=word[len-1];``
word[len-1]=temp;
for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(word[i]+" ");
}
```

Comment: It is very simple code for swaping of first and last word in  String.